# How to write lists of list in xlsx in horizontal using python?

Tags: python, excel, xlsx

I have three nested lists in list new_list = [["first", "second"], ["third", "four"], ["five", "six"]].I want first nested list in first column,second nested list in second column,third nested list in third column in xlsx file using python. i tried below code

```
  import pandas as pd
  import pdb
  new_list = [["first", "second"], ["third", "four"], ["five", "six"]]
  df = pd.DataFrame(new_list)
  writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
  df.to_excel(writer)
```

but it is writing in one below other.please help me out

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the [Pandas dataframe transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html):

```py
import pandas as pd

new_list = [["first", "second"], ["third", "four"], ["five", "six"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(new_list)

# Transpose the dataframe.
df = df.T

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer)

writer.save()
```

Output:

[image]